# Unable to run automation script on same OS version + Robot Framework

Tags: android, python, appium, robotframework

I am trying to run the automation on three different Android devices.
Device details :
Device 1 OS : 6.0
Device 2 OS : 6.0
Device 3 OS : 8.0.

:FOR    ${deviceName}    IN    @{DEVICES}
   \    Open Application  http://localhost:4444/wd/hub  
platformName=Android    deviceName=${deviceName}   
 platformVersion=${osVersion}        app=app-debug.apk  
  automationName=appium    
appActivity=com.example.android.logindemo.MainActivity

When I try to run the above command, the script runs on the first device for two times because there are two 6.0 os Version devices[not running on another 6.0 device].
I am passing device name respective os version in Open Application as an arguments, 
Why is it not running on the respective devices?

Comment: What do your logs say? There should be one log statement for each  iteration of the loop.  Have you verified that `@{DEVICES}` contains what you think it does? What happens if, for example, you replace `open application` with just a log statement so that you can see all of the variables for each iteration?

Comment: please paste some more code here ? why you want to open session for all the devices on same server? what are the errors you are getting

Comment: I am able to see the devices using logs. Right devices only passing. But when we have two same OS devices. it picks the first devices and runs the script on the devices two times, leaves the second devices. In deviceName=${deviceName}  [here I am passing the output one by one which retrieved from the ADB devices command]

Comment: Is `${deviceName}` different for two devices with the same OS? Can you show what the value is for `${deviceName}` for each of the devices?

Comment: ${deviceName}  will have the output of ADB devices command. (i.e serial number). Yes, ${deviceName}  is different for each device but they have same OS version. When trying run on the above devices it takes the first devices and run the script two times .